# ngModel in angular-8. How to store the data accepted from user?

Tags: angular8, two-way-binding

I am trying to accept the value from the User, using text box of one component and store it in a variable. And then I want to use that variable in another component's html * (like accepting any username dynamically from text field using [(ngModel)] of one component and display it in the welcome page of another component. * Can anyone please help me with it's code please. **The code is in angular-8**. Appreciate any help and thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow, please check this article before posting : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

angular has service
which is some kind of state management
you should generate a service 
`ng g s services/nameOfMyService`
 it creates a singleton service which can save your data and make them accessable through all components simply you import service in .ts file of any component you need it 
and inject it like :
`constructor(public anyName: nameOfImportedClassFromMyService){}`

now you can access data through `anyName`
`<div>{{anyName.anyVariableDeclaredInAnyName}} </div>`

https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4